# "We just are diligent“ VS "We are just diligent"

Tags: sentence-construction

> "We just are diligent, and we'll continue to do so."

I saw this sentence quoted by [this article](https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/kidnapped-mollie-tibbetts-details-suspect-030530847.html). "We just are diligent" looks unusual to me. I normally see "We are just diligent" instead. So, is there a nuance?

Comment: No.  It's an odd phrasing either way, but not unusual when someone is speaking impromptu, such as this sheriff answering reporter's questions.  I would have said, *"It's just that we are being diligent in our investigation."*

Comment: Agreed. "We are just diligent" is a more correct way to say it, but it's easy to speak strangely when answering questions and speaking in front of a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either can work, though they would have different stress when spoken.

> We are just diligent

This means that we are simply diligent, or merely diligent. The real nuance depends on context.

> We just are diligent

Stress on this would be on *are*, and slightly on *just*, and it might occur after a question like "how come you're so diligent?" - and it would express the idea that there's no reason, it's just how we are.

Without context, by the way, the other clause of the sentence seems wrong. Context could make it work, but otherwise I'd expect it to be "we'll continue to be so".

So, without context, I would expect the sentence to be a mistake that should have been:

> "We are just diligent, and we'll continue to be so."

However, context could make either part of it right, and it's just about possible that both parts could be right at the same time.